# Real closed interval is perfect

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

A perfect set is a closed set which has no isolated points.

Let $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$. Then $[a,b]$ is perfect. Would the following argument be correct?

By the density of the reals, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there is no $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon(x)\cap [a,b]=\{x\}$. Hence, $[a,b]$ contains no isolated points.

I'm wondering if this would be enough for a proof, or should more details be given?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you mean when you mention the “density of the reals”.

It is clear that $[a,b]$ is closed. If $x\in[a,b]$, in order to prove that $x$ is not an isolated point of $[a,b]$, you need to prove that any neighborhood of $x$ in $[a,b]$ contains some point of $[a,b]$ other than $x$ itself. Since very neighborhood of $x$ contains some interval $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ ($\varepsilon>0$), it will be enough to check for these intervals. If $x<b$, just take some number $x'\in\left(x,\min\{x+\frac\varepsilon2,b\}\right)$. If $x=b$, just take some number $x'\in\left(b-\frac\varepsilon2,b\right)$.